# Date php format day lowercase

Tags: php, date, datetime

In the php doc i found:

> l (lowercase 'L') A full textual representation of the day of the
>   week  Sunday through Saturday
>   (http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

But the result of

```
$d = new \Datetime();
echo $d->format('l');
echo '     ';
echo $d->format('L');
```

is :

> Friday     0

Tested in php 5.5.18 and 5.3.29

Is it a php bug? Or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: In the same doc http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php, you will find the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output is correct:

`$d->format('l');` returns `Friday`:

> A full textual representation of the day of the week. Sunday through Saturday

`$d->format('L')` returns `0`:

> Whether it's a leap year. 1 if it is a leap year, 0 otherwise.

Comment: I'm so stupid! So it isn't possible to have the day of the week sunday through saturday without strtolower...

Comment: No, you have to use `strtolower` :)

Answer (score 1):

It is not a bug in php, You misunderstood it.

```
$d->format('L');
```

returns 1 if the current year is leap year, if not it returns 0.

> *`L`* parameter denotes Whether it's a leap year. It will return  1 if it is a leap year, 0 otherwise.
>
> *`l`* returns A full textual representation of the day of the week

Answer (score 0):

It is not a bug, L(Upper case) represents whether it is leap year or not.

Answer (score 0):

You misinterpreted  [DateTime's](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) man page -

> "w" format char is for day of the week
>   
>   "L" is for leap year.

http://3v4l.org/UC4Tj delivers correct result ("Friday     5") since PHP 5.2